# How to extract a substring from a string in python between a marker and the nth occurrence of another marker

Tags: python, regex, string, find, slice

Here's the string:

```
IP = "http://username:password@192.168.0.66/mjpg/video.mjpg"
```

I'd like to extract the IP address between `@` and the third `/` to pass it as an argument to a function. That's one line among hundreds in a text file which I must loop through extracting only the IP addresses.

The following code doesn't work, and I don't know why. If I replace the `/` with `/mjpg` and remove the (3) it will work, but the video stream after the `/` isn't always mjpg and could be one of hundreds in the script I'm working on. Point is extracting the substring between the "@" and the third "/".

```
print(IP[IP.find("@")+1:IP.find(("/"),3)])
```

Can some spot the error or suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of finding the third occurrence of `/`, you can instead get the first occurrence of `/` after `@`

```
>>> start = IP.find("@")
>>> end   = IP.find("/", start)
>>> IP[start+1:end]
'192.168.0.66'
```

That being said, it is easier to use `re.findall` to do this

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'http:.*?//[^@]*@([0-9.]+)/', IP)
['192.168.0.66']
```

Comment: Thanks Sunitha. It does work. Any idea though why my line of code produces a blank line!

Comment: In your code, what do you expect `IP.find(("/"),3)]` to return? The second arg to `str.find` is the starting position. So it just returns the position of first `/` after the third character